# sqlite data retrieval from another view controller

Tags: ios, sqlite

i have a view Controller called as VegQuantity which does totalcost=(quantity*cost of the dish) and inserts the itemname,quantity,totalcost into a table called as FINALORDER with database name FinalOrder

```
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &FinalOrder) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO FINALORDER (itemname, quantity, totalcost) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", \"%@\")", itemName.text, input.text, output.text];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    sqlite3_prepare_v2(FinalOrder, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        //  status.text = @"Contact added";
        //  name.text = @"";
        //  address.text = @"";
        //  phone.text = @"";
        NSLog(@"added");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Couldnt add");
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(FinalOrder);
}
```

Final View Controller viewdidload method

```
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &FinalOrder) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM FINALORDER"];

    const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(FinalOrder, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *itemname = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            item.text = itemname;

            NSString *qua = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            quantity.text = qua;

            NSString *total = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            totalcost.text=total;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(FinalOrder);
}
```

But i keep getting this error called expected expression before FinalOrder,and is it correct for me to write this code inside viewdidload? i dont have any button in Final view controller i have a button called order in a view controller called as Restaurant which actually shows me Final view controller..am i supposed to search for the db file again in the Final viewcontroller and i am sorry question seems kind of vague but in brief i just want to know how to retrieve and display the data which i have inserted in VegQuantity view controller into the final view controller thanks

Comment: Where do you get this "expected expression" error? Compile error? A crash? Can you describe the particular problem in greater detail? And while I have some minor observations on your code snippets, there's nothing fatally wrong here, so it makes me think the problem rests elsewhere.

Comment: As an aside, if I interpret this right, that you're using a SQLite database to pass data between view controllers. If I'm correct, that, itself, is a little strange. I would only use Core Data and sqlite if I needed persistent storage that would stay around between launches of the app, or if I'm dealing with a lot of data. But let's see if we can fix your problem anyway.

Comment: i get the error on the following lines                              if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &FinalOrder) ==SQLITE_OK)                                                          if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(FinalOrder, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)                                                         sqlite3_close(FinalOrder);

Comment: all above errors are compiler errors,i am not passing any thing using sqlite,i am just trying to retreive the contents of database which were inserted in another view controller

Comment: i have 3 text fields quantity,itemname,totalcost..i calculate the quantity times price and display the respective item name,quantity,totalcost in their resp fields after clicking a done button...now the done button also performs insertion of this values in the database called finalorder

Comment: now in the main menu i have this button called as order..which will let me know what i have ordered along with the itemname,quantity and totalcost..so i need to retrieve this values..now this view is called Final which also contains the same textfields but displays only the retrieved data..i mean the ordered data..i hope you understood what i meant

Comment: Have you done the `#import <sqlite3.h>` at the start of your .m file?

Comment: yes..but i have done it this way #import "/usr/include/sqlite3.h"

Comment: i get  the above 3 errors along with this error"too few arguments to function 'sqlite3_prepare_v2'"

Comment: What is `FinalOrder`? If that's a class, that would give you your `expected expression` error. It should generally be `sqlite3 *myDatabase;` and then `sqlite3_open(dbpath, &myDatabase)`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15851/discussion-between-rob-and-boredtodeath)

Comment: i have declared this in my Final.h file sqlite3 *FinalOrder; and done the same thing above..i still dont understand what is causing the problem :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem must rest in the definition of `FinalOrder` which, on the basis of the error message, looks like has been defined as a class, not as a `sqlite3 *` variable. Given that the scope of your usage of the database is limited to these two methods, I'd suggest defining a `sqlite3 *` within that scope, and use that, such as:

```
- (void)saveRecord
{
    sqlite3      *database;
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char   *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        [self purgeTable:database];

        NSString *insertSQL = @"INSERT INTO FINALORDER (itemname, quantity, totalcost) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [insertSQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [itemName.text UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, [input.text intValue]);
            sqlite3_bind_double(statement, 3, [output.text doubleValue]);

            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                //  status.text = @"Contact added";
                //  name.text = @"";
                //  address.text = @"";
                //  phone.text = @"";
                NSLog(@"added");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"%s Couldn't add; errmsg='%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%s Couldn't prepare; errmsg='%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }

        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Note, in addition to using a `sqlite3 *` variable for the database, to make this a little more robust:

1. I have replaced the `stringWithFormat` statement that built the SQL insert statement with an `INSERT` statement that uses the `?` placeholders and then use `sqlite3_bind_text` to bind values to that statement. This way, if someone entered a value that included a quotation mark, the insert statement will still work (your original implementation would have crashed and/or was susceptible to a SQL injection attack).
2. I have also added the `sqlite3_errmsg` statements so if something goes wrong, I know what the problem was.
3. Rather than treating these three fields as text fields, I'm assuming your table is defined as `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FINALORDER (itemname TEXT, quantity INT, totalcost REAL);` and therefore use text, int, and double bind statements.

This, incidentally, invokes a `purgeTable` method, so if you run it twice, it will remove the old record in there:

```
- (void)purgeTable:(sqlite3 *)database
{
    if (sqlite3_exec(database, "DELETE FROM FINALORDER;", NULL, NULL, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s Couldn't purge table %s", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Anyway, you can then read this data via:

```
- (void)loadRecord
{
    sqlite3      *database;
    const char   *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = @"SELECT * FROM FINALORDER";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [querySQL UTF8String], -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSString *itemname = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
                item.text = itemname;
                //[itemname release]; // if not ARC, uncomment this line

                int qua = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 1);
                quantity.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1d", qua];

                double total = sqlite3_column_double(statement, 2);
                totalcost.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%1.2f", total];
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%s Couldn't prepare; errmsg='%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
    }
}
```

Note,

1. I've added a `sqlite3_errmsg` log statement if the `sqlite3_prepare` fails, and I've retired the `stringWithFormat` (because you weren't formatting anything).
2. Given that `quantity` was `INT` and `total` was `REAL`, I'm retrieving the values using the appropriate variation of `sqlite3_column_text`, `sqlite3_column_int`, or `sqlite3_column_double`, as appropriate.
3. I infer that you're not using ARC and therefore, the `[NSString alloc]` must have an associated `release` or `autorelease`.

Finally, in our chat, you said that you received an error message (presumably an "Undefined Symbols" message) that said:

```
OBJC_CLASS_$"_FinalOrder"
```

This means that you are trying to use an object class of `FinalOrder`, but you haven't defined that class anywhere. Take a look at which .o files it's reporting this error for and look at the corresponding .m file, and look for your use of the `FinalOrder` class there. You clearly have a `FinalOrder` class interface defined somewhere, but never defined the class implementation, or, if you have one, for some reason it's not included in your target's "Compile Sources" listing, so double check it's here:

[image: Add compile source]

Finally, by the way, make sure your database is in the `Documents` folder, not trying to open a copy of the database in your project's bundle (because that's read only). If you have a copy of the database in your bundle, just check to see if you already have it in you `Documents` folder, and if not, copy it from the bundle to the `Documents` folder.